# Flutter: The song does not appear in the audio files and the music player, how can we solve this?

Tags: flutter, file, download

In Flutter, the song was successfully downloaded and it appears in the Music file, but the song does not appear in the audio files and the music player, how can we solve this?

Comment: Are you refreshing your list after downloading the file?

Comment: Show your code or else nobody can help you

Comment: @Vanitas no i don't know how to update can you tell me please

Comment: @ElmarHasanov Share the code snippets by editing your post. So we can get a better understanding of the problem.